# Bootstrap Accordion - adding and removing accordion elements according to screen width

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

The problem is this:

I have a form which links to a database via javascript. I can only have one instance of this form on the page.

Above the laptop size break point, there should be just the form on the page. Below that on tablet and phone, it should be the accordion, collapsed.

How do you set up the accordion to exist around the form, only when in the smaller view sizes? The form is bootstrap responsive already.

Comment: I deleted my answer, I would rewrite the question and give more details, I think the current question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the bar on large and medium screens, just add this 2 classes on the heading div

```
<div class="panel-heading hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
```

Comment: Seriously? *smacks forehead*